# Enforcing PSBT Signature Rules: Finalizer/Extractor and Deserialization Implementation

Tags: taproot, bip174-psbt, p2tr

Should PSBT finalizers/extractors and deserialization functions enforce the rule that a taproot schnorr signature should only append a SIGHASH_* unless it is SIGHASH_DEFAULT (0), or is it left to the implementer's discretion?

Ref: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki#cite_note-21

Comment: Are you asking whether the finalizer should append a sighash byte for SIGHASH_DEFAULT signatures? Well, no, since it would make it invalid?

Comment: No, i am asking this - should a finalizer check the signature (PSBT_IN_TAP_KEY_SIG/PSBT_IN_TAP_SCRIPT_SIG) and remove SIGHASH_DEFAULT and if it exist and then use the 64 byte signature? Or throw error?

Comment: Currently, bitcoinjs-lib finalizer blindly adds the 65 byte signature to the witness even if the sighash is SIGHASH_DEFAULT.

Comment: I believe the extractor role should check the validity of the transaction it produces, therefore it should explicitly error. Let me post a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to how to treat invalid signatures provided in a PSBT. I believe there is some room for implementation-defined behaviour with regard to the finalizer role. For instance if it can get around the invalid signatures by satisfying another spending path.

However the [specification for the extractor role](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0174.mediawiki#transaction-extractor) is pretty clear:

> The Extractor should produce a fully valid, network serialized transaction if all inputs are complete.

Since the input finalizer and transaction extractor roles are often combined, and since explicit is better than implicit, i believe it would make sense to explicitly raise an error on an invalid signature. But nothing prescribes it in the specification itself.

Comment: Spec is not clear. But the case you made makes sense. Thanks.